# How do you remove the collider that comes with the Unity Character Controller component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do you remove the collider that comes with the Unity Character Controller component?

Comment: The collider is part of the controller.  The character controller has a number of flaws unfortunately.  From Docs:  `[The Character Controller] is simply a capsule shaped Collider
 which can be told to move in some direction from a script.`  excerpt from the first paragraph under details of the [Character Controller Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html)